# Store Function Value into temporary table

Tags: mysql, plsql

Hi i'm currently trying to run a SQL query on a 15 000 + entry dataset. I'm using a custom Mysql function to determine the start of the current week and the end of it. Probleme is, I'm using those values in the `WHERE` clause of my query so it is executed at each comparaison, which take a lot of time. 
 I've discovered that those values never change, so I need to execute the function only one time to get the value, I can then pass the value to the `WHERE` clause. 

The function itself does not takes long to execute, it's doing it 60 000 times that takes a long time.

I was wondering if there is a way to save those values into some kind of table where I could check if the start and end of the week has already been calculated and if so, use those value. 

 I tried using a temporary table but I would need to know when the query is done so I could delete it.

Here is my code so far :

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(otherShifts.sft_end, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z'), 
                            STR_TO_DATE(otherShifts.sft_start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.000Z'))) / 3600 as timestamps
                    FROM shift_sft as otherShifts,
                         shift_sft as originalShift
                    WHERE (
                        otherShifts.sft_start BETWEEN getStartOfWeek(originalShift.sft_id) AND getEndOfWeek(originalShift.sft_id) OR
                        otherShifts.sft_end BETWEEN getStartOfWeek(originalShift.sft_id) AND getEndOfWeek(originalShift.sft_id))
                    AND originalShift.sft_id = 1;
```

getStartOfWeek :

```
create function getStartOfWeek(shiftId int) returns varchar(122)
BEGIN
      DECLARE shiftStart varchar(122);
      DECLARE currentUserId INT(11);
      DECLARE currentSunday DATETIME;
      DECLARE currentWeekStart DATETIME;
      DECLARE currentStartingWeekSetting int;
      SELECT sft_start, sft_usr_id INTO shiftStart, currentUserId FROM shift_sft WHERE sft_id = shiftId;
      SET currentSunday :=  DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(shiftStart, 'T', 1), '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(shiftStart, 'T', 1),  '%Y-%m-%d'))) DAY);
       SELECT FIELD(sde_day_week_start,'sun','mon', 'tue', 'wen', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat')
       FROM setting_default_sde, setting_business_sbu, v_user_business
       WHERE v_user_business.usr_id = 1
       AND setting_business_sbu.sbu_sde_id = setting_default_sde.sde_id
       AND setting_business_sbu.sbu_bus_id = v_user_business.bus_id;
       SET currentWeekStart := DATE_ADD(currentSunday, INTERVAL (currentStartingWeekSetting - 1) DAY);
       RETURN DATE_FORMAT(currentWeekStart, '%Y-%m-%d');
     END;
```

getEndOfWeek:

```
create function getEndOfWeek(shiftId int) returns varchar(122)
BEGIN
   DECLARE startOfWeek varchar(122);
   DECLARE endOfWeek DATETIME;
   SELECT getStartOfWeek(shiftId) INTO startOfWeek;
   SET endOfWeek := DATE_ADD(startOfWeek, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
   RETURN DATE_FORMAT(endOfWeek, '%Y-%m-%d');
 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a table with every day for the next few years:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
     dy DATE NOT NULL,   -- every day
     bow DATE NOT NULL,  -- date (yyyy/mm/dd) of the Beginning Of Week
     eow DATE NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(dy)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then, *instead of having a function*, `JOIN` to that table to fetch the bow and/or eow needed.

Meanwhile, `DATE_FORMAT(some_date, '%a')` yields `Sun`, `Mon`, etc.  And `WEEKDAY(some_date)` gives you 0 for Monday, etc.  These might simplify some of your code.